# Estoy haciendo una pagina con JSF pero no muestra los componenetes "u:"

Tags: java, jsf

Estoy haciendo una pagina sencilla (les dejo el código y ss abajo) pero no me muestra los componenetes.

```
<body>
<h2>h:inputText example</h2>
<hr/>
<h:form>
    <h3>Read-Only input text box</h3>
    <h:inputText value = "Hello World!" readonly = "true"/>
    <h3>Normal input text box</h3>
    <h:inputText value = "Hello World"/>
</h:form>

<h2>h:inputSecret example</h2>
<hr />

<h:form>
    <h3>Read-Only input password box</h3>
    <h:inputSecret value = "password" readonly = "true"/>
    <h3>Read-Only input text box</h3>
    <h:inputText value = "password"/>
</h:form>


</body>
```

[image: No me muestra ningún componene (inputText, InputSecret)]

Lo que quiero es que me muestre los componentes. Abajo les dejo el web.xml y pom.xml

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
<display-name>JSF Tutorial</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsf</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ingesis.jee.tutorials</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-tutorial</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version.source>1.8</java.version.source>
    <java.version.target>1.8</java.version.target>
    <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
    <jsf.version>2.1.7</jsf.version>
    <primefaces.version>6.0</primefaces.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version.source}</source>
                <target>${java.version.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/jsf-tutorial-1.0/resources</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Comment: No tienes los namespaces de los taglibs, por eso no te muestra lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

En la parte superior de tu HTML, verifica que tengas correctamente declarados los atajos, me refiero específacmente a "h:"

```
<html xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
```

Saludos!

Comment: no se llaman atajos, son namespaces y pertenecen a taglibs específicos, como solamene está usando el primero no necesita los otros.

Answer (score 0):

Yo pase por lo mismo, estoy utilizando eclipse:

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
Build id: 20200313-1211

y en el archivo *.xhtml tenia lo siguiente:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
```

lo que hice fue cambiarlo por:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

y listo empezo a mostrarme los componente.